# What does "DM at RLSB" mean?

Tags: terminology

I read "DM at RLSB" in a note from the medical personnel on a patient in the ICU. I know that DM typically stands for *diabetes mellitus*, and that RLSB typically stands for  *right lower sternal border*, but I am quite puzzled by the phrase "DM at RLSB".

Context (which I am legally allowed to reproduce here):

> T: 98.4, P: 88, BP: 101/50, R: 20, 97% 2L NC
>  GEN: elderly,
>   chronically-ill appearing male, alert x 2
>  HEENT: anicteric, normal
>   conjunctivea, pupils equal and 
>  minimally reactive to light
>   bilaterally, EOMI, OMM dry, OP 
>  clear, neck supple, no JVD, masked
>   facies, mild faical droop
>  Cardiac: irregulary irregular rhythm,
>   II/VI SEM at apex, II/VI 
>  **DM at RLSB**
>  PUlm: min crackles at
>   bases b/l
>  ABD: NABS, soft, NT/ND, left sided hernia, no HSM
>   Ext: LLE shortened and externally rotated, left elbow with 5cm 
>   skin tear and associated abrasion, actively dripping blood. 2+ 
>   radial pulses bilaterally, trace DP left, 1+ DP right, LLE 
>   slightly cooler than RLE, sensation intact to light touch and 
>   able to wiggle digits distally in upper and lower extremities 
>   bilaterally. No significant hematoma noted at left hip. 1+ LE 
>   edema 1/3 up calves bilaterally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Diastolic Murmur [heard maximally at the] Right Lower Sternal Border`

This is not the most typical description of any murmur, but it can be consistent with aortic regurgitation. Note that this patient had two murmurs described. In addition to DM/RLSB, he had a SEM = `systolic ejection murmur` (SEM). Both were described as II/IV intensity (read: *two out of six*), indicating a murmur that was faint but could be heard without difficulty.*

[This is a good review](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK346/) on diastolic murmurs, usually considered to be an indicator of pathology. In contrast, [systolic murmurs](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK345/) are at times consistent with normal physiology.

---

<sub>* Traditionally. Modern cardiologists tell me that those of us not trained in the good-ole’-days of cardiac auscultation tend to experience difficulty up to a higher threshold of intensity.</sub>